# What can you conclude about the following IVP from the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for first order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what can you conclude about the following IVP from the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for first order nonlinear ODE?

￼[image]

here is the theorem: [the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/existence/existence.html)
[image]

I could only get the domain involves $(t+y(t))$, i couldn't get where $f$ and $df/dy$ are continuous.

here, $f(t,y)=\sqrt{\tan(t+y(t)}$.

[image]

Comment: What are the hypothesis of the theorem?

Comment: [link](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/existence/existence.html)

Comment: So see if this IVP satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: but i could only get the domain involves (t+y(t)), i couldn't get where f and df/dy are continuous.

Comment: OK. First identify $f$. What is $f(t,y)$ here?

Comment: (tan(t+y(t))^(1/2))

Comment: Not exactly, it is $f(t,y)=\sqrt{\tan(t+y)}$. Can you differentiate this with respect to $y$?

Comment: could you please see the post above? I have edited since I don't know how to type it here. sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to use latex, lol. Sorry abt that.

Comment: OK. It's fine. So now you just have to determine what $(x_0, y_0)$ is and find $a$ and $b$ such that $\frac {\mathrm df}{\mathrm dy}$ continuous in the rectangle. I would say you don't even have to find $a$ and $b$, just explain how you can be sure they exist or do not exist. I'm going to bed now. Good luck.

Comment: ok!!thx!! gdnite

Answer (score 0):

As you found out,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac1{2\sqrt{\sin(t+y)\cos^3(t+y)}}
$$
which is bounded on all (closed) rectangles that avoid the lines $t+y=k\frac\pi2$, $k\in\Bbb Z$.